# Rows removed from a datatable are also removed from the session variable that created the datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

I am noticing some strange behavior when working with datatables stored in session variables. Removing a row from a datatable that is created from a session variable appears to also modify the session variable as demonstrated below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvResults" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSelectUserToRemove" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Remove" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnCommand="Command" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
            dtResults.Columns.Add("id");

            dtResults.Rows.Add();
            dtResults.Rows[0]["id"] = "1";
            dtResults.Rows.Add();
            dtResults.Rows[1]["id"] = "2";

            Session["id"] = dtResults;
            gvResults.DataSource = dtResults;
            gvResults.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Remove")
        {
            DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)Session["id"];
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == dtTemp.Rows[i]["id"].ToString())
                {
                    dtTemp.Rows[i].Delete(); //Should just remove the row from the datatable.
                }
            }
            dtTemp.AcceptChanges();
        }
        DisplayData();
    }

    protected void DisplayData()
    {
        gvResults.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["id"];
        gvResults.DataBind(); //Should display both rows because I did not save the modified datatable back to this session variable.
    }
}
```

I am not saving the modified `dtTemp` datatable back to the `Session["id"]` variable. It is my understanding that there should be 1 row in `dtTemp`, because one row was deleted, and 2 rows in `Session["id"]` when calling `DisplayData`. However, only one row is displayed in the gridview after `DisplayData` runs.

I am hoping there is someone out there that can shed some light on why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `dtTemp` and the session variable are object references that both point to the same object.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer along with mkocubinski's helped. I created a new datatable, cloned the columns from `dtTemp` then used the ImportRow function to copy only the data I needed.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)Session["id"];
```

Does not do what you think it does. Since the `DataTable` is a reference type, you're just grabbing a pointer to that object's location in memory (which happens to be in the SessionState variable), not creating a fresh copy of it.

If you want to operate on the `DataTable` without modifying the one in Session, you'll need to look into a Clone pattern, like [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)